# Connect to secured and hidden SSID without manually editing config files

Tags: wifi, pi-3

Is there an alternative to manually editing configuration files if I want to connect my PI 3 to a hidden -and secure- SSID?

Comment: Hiding a SSID adds no security.  Why waste your time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you, like me, don't feel like manually editing the interfaces and wpa_supplicant config files AND you own or have admin access to the network you're trying to connect to, then this simple trick should do it:

- set your router to broadcast your ssid (only 2.4Ghz mind you) for like 2 minutes.
- your pi should list your ssid, connect to it with your passkey.
- set your router to NOT broadcast it again.
- reboot your pi and it should pick it up automatically even if hidden on each start.

Tested it myself and working.

Answer (score 0):

execute the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk
```

and wait for it to install itself on your RPi.
Double-click on the ***Internet/Wicd Network Manager*** menu item.
If it does not list your hidden essid, then change your router settings
to show the hidden essid (You're better off protecting the essid with a passphrase, rather than hiding the essid).
If that doesn't appeal to you execute the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

This will install nmcli on your RPi.
Use nmcli:

```
sudo nmcli con add conectionName PiHostName ifname wlan0 type wifi ssid HiddenSSID
sudo nmcli con modify PiHostName wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
sudo nmcli con modify PiHostName wifi-sec.psk HiddenPassPhrase 
sudo kill wpa_supplicant
sudo nmcli con up PiHostName
```